# Android background animation issue

Tags: android, android-animation

I have linear layout and background drawable on it, and ImageView inside which I'm animating. If I remove that background image from linear layout animation is very smooth, but when I put the background image back on, it's very very slow. Any idea why and how to solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/background"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/demoImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/temp"
android:maxWidth="200dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm applying only these two animations to image:

```
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomout);
```

And they work fine without this part, but extremely slowly (frame by frame) with this part:

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

This background.png is 750x600px png file ~40kb size.

**ANSWER**

For some reason (don't know why), after creating custom drawable like this animation is smooth again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<color android:color="#FFFFFF"></color>
</item>
<item>
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="top"
    />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: code + ur image size + more info.

Comment: I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the scaletype in xml code to fitCenter. centerInside doesn't reduce the amount of data that is being processed and just zooms the image in to fit in the container.

Here:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/demoImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/temp"
android:maxWidth="200dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Hi @KoalaKoalified but I don't have a problem with this ImageView I had a problem with background image in LinearLayout.

Comment: Yes, sorry for late comment.